# Where to put the static initialization statements for EF 4.3 Code First and Migrations when working with a class library?

Tags: vb6, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I am just getting my feet wet using Entity Framework 4.3 and Migrations for a SQLServerCompact 4.0 database, so I am using the simplest possible methods to get things started. Following the advice in [this blog](http://blog.larud.net/using-ef-4-3-code-first-migrations-with-sql-server-compact-4-0) I added the initialization statements below to the Main method of a console application. This all works very well.

```
 Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = New SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0")
 Database.SetInitializer(Of MySQLCompactDbContext)(New MySQLCompactDBInitializer)
```

But in production the code addressing the database will be located in a class library that will be accessed through COM-interop from a Visual Basic 6 application. So there is no natural entry point for the code where to put the static methods mentioned above.

Where can I put them?
Please point out the alternative way using the config file if necessary.

Comment: A *static* constructor of your `MySQLCompactDbContext` is a possible place. The constructor is called once when you create a context instance for the very first time in your application. I'm using this approach in a class library sometimes and it works. I am not sure though if this is safe when you access the lib via COM-Interop.